# How can i get list of topics from kafka server using kafka-node library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka

I wanted to create new topic on kafka server but before that i want to retrieve topic list from my server , How can i achieve that once connection is established ?

main.js

```
  var groupId = 'test1';
    var clientId = "consumer-" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
    var options = {autoCommit: true, fetchMaxWaitMs: 100, fetchMaxBytes: 10 * 1024 * 1024, groupId: groupId};
    console.log("Started consumer: ", clientId);
    var consumer_client = new Client(kafkaConn,clientId);
    var client = new Client(consumer_client.connectionString,clientId);
    var consumer = new HighLevelConsumer(client, topics, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

No real direct way to do this with `kafka-node`, but you can do it with `node-zookeeper-client`. If you have a `kafka.Client` instantiated, you already have access to a `zookeeper` client. You can just do:

```
client.zk.client.getChildren("/brokers/topics", (err, children, stats) => {
  children.forEach(child => console.log(child));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old question but after searching an answer for that I found out that there is a more proper api in kafka node:

```js
const client = new kafka.KafkaClient();
const admin = new kafka.Admin(client);
admin.listTopics((err, res) => {
  console.log('topics', res);
});
```

https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node#listtopicscb