# Consume multiple topics in a single consumer on kafka

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is there any way for kafka to cosume on a single consumer with multiple topics?

Here is my consumer code, it works fine with single topic

```
let consumer = new Consumer(
        client,
        [{ topic: '1234', offset: 0, partition: 0 }],
        {
            autoCommit: true,
            fetchMaxWaitMs: 1000,
            fetchMaxBytes: 1024 * 1024,
            encoding: 'utf8',
            fromOffset: false
        }
    );
    consumer.on('message', async function (message: any) {
        console.log(
            'kafka-> ',
            message.value
        );
    })
```

Comment: Maybe you can, see this implementation (https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/issues/99)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearly a list, you should be able to add multiple topics in the consumer.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node#consumer says u can do as below. (Would be wise not to assign partition, and let zookeeper handle it)

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
Consumer = kafka.Consumer,
client = new kafka.KafkaClient(),
consumer = new Consumer(
    client,
    [
        { topic: 't', partition: 0 }, { topic: 't1', partition: 1 }
    ],
    {
        autoCommit: false
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks @abbin, just wanted to ask one more thing is there any way to add all topics which are present in kafka?

Comment: May this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975055/how-can-i-get-list-of-topics-from-kafka-server-using-kafka-node-library